# Handling connection timeout error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Sometimes when my server is down or busy, I get an error saying "connection timeout" while connecting to MySQL. But with the error the program also crashes. My question is how can I prevent crashing, it would be better to show a msgbox when this happens. (visual basic 2010)

I use this,

```
Dim connStr As String = "Database=mydatabase;" & _
                    "Data Source=datasrc;" & _
                    "User Id=myid;Password=mypass"

Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)

connection.Open() // I get error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to see the ThreadExceptionDialog, you'll need to catch the exception in your code.   For example:

```
  Public Function ConnectToDbase() As Boolean
    Try
      connection.Open()
      '--- etc
      Return True
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Could not connect to the database")
      Return False
    End Try
  End Function
```

The burden is now on the code that uses ConnectToDbase() to do something meaningful when it returns False.

Comment: That's the "do something meaningful" burden I talked about.  Don't keep trying to use the dbase when you got a False return.  Maybe you ought to tell the user to call support and terminate your program.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can happen is if you don't properly dispose your connections.  For example, say an exception is thrown due to a problem in your sql code, and it's caught, but caught in such a way that you never call `connection.Close()`.  Eventually you will run out of available connections and your `connection.Open()` call will fail and timeout when trying to connect.  To avoid this, you should create your connections with a "using" block, like this:

```
Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr), _
      command As New MySqlCommand("sql statement here")

    connection.Open()


End Using ''# connection is guaranteed to be closed here, even if an exception is thrown
```

Comment: it doesnt work when i call connection function second time, i still get error